# Split Monolog log messages if exceeding max line length

Tags: php, monolog

I'm pushing log messages using [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) to a `Handler` that has a maximum message length restriction of 1024 characters.

I am looking for the best way to intercept my log messages and if exceeding 1024 characters split them up into two (or more).

I could build a `Formatter` that simply cuts the message at 1024 characters but I want to preserve the information.

Next thought was to use a `Processor` but it simply receives the record in question and there is no way to inject another record.

So I guess the proper way would be to build a custom handler, e.g. `MessageLengthLimitHandler`, in which I can wrap the real handler receiving my messages in the end.

I've tried looking at other Handlers and it seems all I would need to implement is the `handle()` function, rest could be inherited from [AbstractHandler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractHandler.php).
However, I'm a bit unsure what the proper way to split one `$record` into two would be - any suggestions?

As soon as I have them split I can simply pass them on using `$this->handler->handle($record)` for every record (or by passing an array to `handleBatch()`)

Comment: **To my mind**: A custom handler could be a good idea. If you look at the `StreamHandler` it implements the `AbstractProcessingHandler` which provide a function `write()`. Maybe you can extend it from your own class and override it.

Comment: @Debflav Yes, I'm aware of that (even if I believe `AbstractHandler` might be enough in this case) but my real question is how I in the best way split one $record into two?